# How to save multiple figures, not subplots, produced in a for loop as one figure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter Notebook, I write the following code, [as MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50)
for x in range(4):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x1)
    plt.savefig(str(x)+".png") # save figures separately
```

It produces 4 plots, as expected. They are below each other in a row.

**I want to have a single saved output, containing all 4 plots.** I don't mind if Jupyter Notebook does not show the plots as long as they are saved.

My attempt: save the figures separately, as 0.png, 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, then merge them vertically.

I hope there is an easier way to do this. How can I have a single saved output?

**EDIT:**

As suggested, I could do subplots, like this:

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4)
fig.set_size_inches(8,12)
x1 = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50)
for ax in axes:
    ax.plot(x1)
plt.savefig("save_fig.png")
```

I want to have many figures, not one fiugre with many subplots.
How can I save the multiple figures without using subplots?

Comment: Create a figure with 4 subplots?

Comment: Use `plt.subplots`. Read the basic documentation.

Comment: There are several duplicates of this question with different answers on creating subplots. I would suggest to mark it as duplicate.

Comment: yes, subplot method works. I wanted to have other method, but it does the job.

Comment: I dont think it is dublicate, because the subplot method basically creates one plot and than saves that, and I'd like to save many plots as one, so the Q is not answered by subplotting.

Comment: Once it is saved how can you tell the difference between multiple figures or multiple subplots?  If subplots actually give you the same results it's a duplicate; if the results are different explain how in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initalize a figure and add a subplot for each loop. then save after your loops are finished!

Comment: Yes, I like that method as a work-around, but does not really show how to sova multiple plots and not one big plot with many subplots.